# Laravel + NGINX CSS/JS 404 not found

Tags: laravel, nginx

- Laravel 5.5 fresh
- nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

When I go to: `http://<my-ip>/crm/` all is working great, I get the Laravel welcome page, all js and css are loading correctly.

When I go to `http://<my-ip>/crm/register` - I get 404 for css and js.

This is my conf:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name _;


        rewrite ^/((?!en)[a-z]*)/home$ /index.php?lang=$1&$args last;
        rewrite ^/((?!en)[a-z]*)/sitemap.xml$ /sitemap.xml last;
        rewrite /pigeon/(.*)$ /pigeon/index.php?/ last;
        rewrite /crm/(.*)$ /crm/index.php?/ last;

        if (!-f $request_filename){
                set $rule_52 1$rule_52;
        }
        if ($rule_52 = "1"){
                rewrite ^/(.*)(?<!php)$ /$1.php last;
        }


        location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location /pigeon {
           alias /var/www/html/pigeon/public;
           try_files $uri $uri/ @pigeon;

          location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
           }
        }


        location /crm {
           alias /var/www/html/crm/public;
                      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location /crm.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
                access_log off;
                expires max;
        }

          location ~ \.php$ {
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
           }
        }
```

How do I fix this conf file to catch css and js files correctly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It seems allright what you have there in the server block.Although you might be better off if you add a proper server name.
Check this question and see if it helps. It has to do with the symlink to `var/www/html` for your `crm`, if you used one.

[Laravel 8 + nginx - app.css and app.js resources from public/ not loading - 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337405/laravel-8-nginx-app-css-and-app-js-resources-from-public-not-loading-404)

And if not you could still use the online CDN's from bootstrap.Also in the question.